# Getting Involved?

Tags: open-source, project, community

I've been sitting at my computer for about an hour and a half, browsing around and trying to find something worthwhile to do that I'd enjoy. The fact that I'm here shows you that I didn't come up with anything.

Anyways, I was wondering about good ways to get involved with open source projects and/or contributing to stuff, without being an expert in whichever language(s) being used, if that's even possible. If it helps, I'm looking for web-based projects especially, so...yeah.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!